# Check if a String has a year in it

Tags: java, string

Is there a easiest way to check if a string has a year in it(say a 4 digit number) and also to find the number of time a 4 digit number is present in the string.

eg  `"My test string with year 1996 and 2015"`

Output

`Has year - YES
number of times - 2
values - 1996 2015`

I thought of doing a split string and check each and every word, but wanted to check if there is any effective way.

Comment: Use a regex? Something along the linex of `^|[\W](\d{4})[\W]|$" ?

Comment: Eh, `"possible counter example: 1000 and 9999"` - do you want `1000` and, esp. `9999` being treated as years?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I will handle that in the client side , for now just a 4 digit check is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[0-9]{4}$
```

Explanation:

```
^     : Start anchor
[0-9] : Character class to match one of the 10 digits
{4} : Range quantifier. exactly 4.
$     : End anchor
```

And here a sample code:

```
    String text = "My test string with year 1996 and 2015 and 1999, and 1900-2000";
    text = text.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "#"); //simple solution for replacing all non digits. 
    String[] arr = text.split("#");

    boolean hasYear = false;
    int matches = 0;
    StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();

    for(String s : arr){
        if(s.matches("^[0-9]{4}$")){
            hasYear = true;
            matches++;
            values.append(s+" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("hasYear: " + hasYear);
    System.out.println("number of times: " + matches);
    System.out.println("values: " + values.toString().trim());
```

Output:

```
hasYear: true
number of times: 5
values: 1996 2015 1999 1900 2000
```

Comment: For years I would recommend that regex if you are sure it should just work for years between 1000 and 2999: `^[1-2][0-9]{3}$`. Else you could check the resulting numbers afterwards for a given date range (e.g. between 1970 and 2100).

Comment: @SebastianBaumhekel Yes you are right, but the Questioner wanted four digits. Qoute: "I will handle that in the client side , for now just a 4 digit check is fine"

Comment: This won't find years next to punctuation characters (or tabs), like in "that was in 2015." You may need to use `\b` for word boundary checking and use the regex on the whole string instead of splitting at spaces first.

Comment: Your explanation of the `{4}` is slightly off: it does not mean maximum of 4 times, it means exactly 4 times.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's already a nice solution using regexes i'll present mine without regexes:

```
private static List<String> findNumbers(String searchStr) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int numbers = 0, first = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < searchStr.length(); i++) {
        char ch = searchStr.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            first = first < 0 ? i : first;
            numbers++;
        } else { 
            if (numbers == 4)
                list.add(searchStr.substring(first, i));
            numbers = 0;
            first = -1;
        }
    }
    if (numbers == 4)
        list.add(searchStr.substring(first, first+4));
    return list;
}
```